# How do i solve this? I keep getting this while installing ionic app on Mobile devices

Tags: ionic3

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at Object.escapeHtml (C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\helpers.js:253:10)
    at generateCodeBlock (C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:187:77)
    at generateDiagnosticHtml (C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:179:12)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.printDiagnostics (C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:15:39)
    at C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:158:34
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at transpileWorker (C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at C:\Users\Sagar\desktop\IonicProject\OnlineStore\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? If not how are you compiling it?